# Just a complain about an unfair vote

Tags: support

It is not my habit to complain, but here I think a user down votes too much

[Domain Not Resolving to Forwarded IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/230489/domain-not-resolving-to-forwarded-ip/230492#230492)

I think it is unfair, both for the question and the (my) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the guy has a right to downvote whatever he wants, but the FAQ suggests leaving constructive feedback.  In my opinion, the goal is to help the question asker and answerers improve.  [This person](https://serverfault.com/users/67675/poige) didn't contribute anything positive to a perfectly valid and well-written question.

Poige, if you don't want to be helpful, why are you here?

And "wet-nursing"?  Really?  Is a comment like that really going to be considered okay here by the moderators?  Are we professionals or are we in high school?  (Actually, some of the teens on here are very professional, no offense to anyone still in high school who has some good to contribute).

Answer (score 7):

Votes are individual expression, and people are free to vote however they wish, so long as they do not game the system to earn extra rep.